# grep No such file or directory

Tags: bash

I am learning basics of bash and I run into troubles. When I try to list files from dev which end with one or two digits I permanently get "No such file or directory".

```
ls /dev | grep ^.*[0-9]{1,2}$
ls /dev | grep -E ^.*[0-9]{1,2}$
ls /dev | egrep ^.*[0-9]{1,2}$
ls /dev | grep ^.*\[0-9\]\{1,2\}$
```

All of those commands end with the same response. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's `ls` not `less`. The latter is a *pager* (it lists files).

Comment: ...and `ls | grep` isn't good practice, either -- there are better ways to get a filtered list of files. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: see also http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs for the best-practice way to get a filtered list of files (when you don't have needs that force regex-based filtering).

Comment: Also, you need to quote your expressions passed to `grep`, or they're prone to being modified by the shell before they get to the `grep` command. See how the examples here are using single-quotes to protect such content.

Comment: By the way -- when do you think `^.*[0-9]{1,2}$` will differ in what it does or doesn't match from `[0-9]$` (or, better, `[[:digit:]]$`)?

Comment: I need files that names end with 1 or two digits. so just [0-9] is not what I am looking for. This is pure academics, so I understand there are better commands than ls. I would just like to know how to make this one work.

Comment: The observation here is that any name that ends in two digits also ends in one digit. If you want 1 or 2 but not 3, you have to use e.g. `[^0-9][0-9]{1,2}$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
find /dev -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*[0-9]'
```

We are using `find` here because, in general, one should *never* [parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

`find /dev -maxdepth 1` finds all the files in `/dev` (but we stop it from  searching `/dev`'s subdirectories).

`-regex '.*[0-9]'` limits the output of `find` to files whose names (excluding any directory) that match the regular expression `.*[0-9]`.  It is not necessary to anchor the regex to match from beginning to end of the file name: this is find's default behavior.

By default, `find` uses emacs-style regular expressions.  GNU `find` can optionally, using `-regextype`, use one of four other regex styles: posix-awk, posix-basic, posix-egrep, and posix-extended.  See `man find` for details.

Note that, because `.` matches numbers among other characters, the regex `.*[0-9]{1,2}` matches 1 or any number of more numbers at the end.  This makes it equivalent to `.*[0-9]`

#### Simplification:

As Benjamin mentions in the comments, this is simple enough that a *regex* is not needed.  Using instead a *glob*:

```
find /dev -maxdepth 1 -name '*[0-9]'
```

#### Rejecting files whose names end in three or more digits

This will find files whose names whose names have at least one non-digit character and end with one or two but not more digits:

```
find /dev -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*[^[:digit:]][[:digit:]]{1,2}'
```

The following might be good enough if you just want to display the file names on the screen **but not parse them as part of a pipeline**.  This will find files whose names have at least three characters and end with one or two but not more digits:

```
ls /dev/*[^[:digit:]]?[[:digit:]]
```

This `ls` solution does have one hitch: it will reject a file name like `a1b2` even though it ends with one digit.  Since `/dev` usually doesn't have that naming style, this is probably not much of a problem.

In the above two approaches, I used `[:digit:]` because it is unicode-safe.  If you are in a locale where that doesn't matter, you can use `0-9` instead, if you prefer:

```
find /dev -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*[^0-9][0-9]{1,2}'
```

Or:

```
ls /dev/*[^0-9]?[0-9]
```

Comment: You don't even need regexes, do you? Could just use globbing with `-name '*[0-9]'` instead.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Good point.  Thanks.  Answer updated with a glob example.

Comment: @cAMPy As per your clarification,  I updated my answer with methods to limit the final numbers to one or two digits but not more.

Answer (score 3):

The command you're looking for is:

```
ls /dev | grep -E '^.*[0-9]{1,2}$'
```

- Use `ls`, not `less`, to list a directory
- Regex ranges conflict with bash brace expansion, and therefore requires quoting to keep bash from interpreting it (this is why you get a file-not-found error)
- Regex ranges (`{1,2}`) are a feature of POSIX ERE, and requires `egrep` or `-E`

Doing anything with `ls` output is frowned upon though. The better way of doing this is with just a regular glob (here with `printf` to output it, instead of passing it to something else):

```
printf "%s\n" /dev/*[0-9]
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `less` with `ls` in each of your commands.

UPDATE:

I see you updated your question with `ls` but have not completed the update to include proper shell quoting. Look at other responses for examples.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the pattern argument to `grep` in quotes. Without quotes, the `*` character makes it a filename wildcard, and there are no files that match that pattern in the current directory, so you get that error message.

```
ls /dev | grep '^.*[0-9]{1,2}$'
```

And as other answers have pointed out, the command to list the files in a directory is `ls`, `less` is for viewing the contents of a text file.